# Including C in Android: CFAbsoluteTime, CFGregorianDate, etc

Tags: android, c

I have a cross-platform project which involves using the same C source library in both ios and Android.

The ios version works well, but when I'm including the library in Android, I'm getting errors with some CoreFoundation types such as CFAbsoluteTime and CFGregorianDate.

I've tried using [CoreFoundation Lite](https://github.com/mlabbe/CoreFoundation), but configuring the prerequisites has been a mess. It feels like overkill for just a couple of datatypes.

Am I on the right track here? Are there "quick" replacements for CFAbsoluteTime and CFGregorianDate, or should I be trying to make the library work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when I'm including the library in Android, I'm getting errors with the CFAbsoluteTime and CFGregorianDate types

It would appear that [`CFGregorianDate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/cfgregoriandate) and [`CFAbsoluteTime`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/cfabsolutetime?language=objc) are classes from an Apple SDK ("Core Foundation").

> should I rewrite the C to remove the offending data types?

The Android NDK does not contain Core Foundation APIs. So, either remove references to those APIs, or find some cross-platform port of them.

Comment: Thanks! I think I was looking for more specific libraries (but was very unclear), or thoughts on whether it were smarter and cleaner to just rewrite. I'm deeper into it now though, so I'll update with code samples.